# google appengine issue - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.copyOf(Ljava/util/Collection

Tags: google-app-engine, guava

I have a google charts app that gets data from the mysql in the local development environment and Cloud SQL instance on the app engine environment. In the local eclipse environment I had the same issue which I resolved by adding the guava jars to the eclipse plugin. I am not sure what I need to do on the remote appengine environment to resolve this issue.

The appengine error log :

```
2013-08-20 05:30:56.160 /oldv2reports/getData?url=jdbc:google:rdbms://onlinederivatives2:oldd/oldd&table=rep_moti_5day_average_data&tq=select%20price_timestamp%2C%20price%20where%20symbol%20%3D%20'ABB'&tqx=reqId%3A1 500 11ms 0kb Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.71 Safari/537.36
65.24.104.225 - - [20/Aug/2013:05:30:56 -0700] "GET /oldv2reports/getData?url=jdbc:google:rdbms://onlinederivatives2:oldd/oldd&table=rep_moti_5day_average_data&tq=select%20price_timestamp%2C%20price%20where%20symbol%20%3D%20\'ABB\'&tqx=reqId%3A1 HTTP/1.1" 500 0 "http://onlinederivatives2.appspot.com/OLDv2ReportsQuery.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.71 Safari/537.36" "onlinederivatives2.appspot.com" ms=12 cpu_ms=39 app_engine_release=1.8.3 instance=00c61b117ca0e915b029dbea0126709e88259c36
W 2013-08-20 05:30:56.157
Error for /oldv2reports/getData
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.copyOf(Ljava/util/Collection;)Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableList;
    at com.google.visualization.datasource.query.QuerySelection.getColumns(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.visualization.datasource.query.Query.validate(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.visualization.datasource.query.parser.QueryBuilder.parseQuery(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.visualization.datasource.DataSourceHelper.parseQuery(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.visualization.datasource.DataSourceHelper.parseQuery(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.visualization.datasource.DataSourceRequest.createQueryFromRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.visualization.datasource.DataSourceRequest.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.visualization.datasource.DataSourceHelper.executeDataSourceServletFlow(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.visualization.datasource.DataSourceServlet.doGet(Unknown Source)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:266)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:439)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:435)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:442)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:186)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:306)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:298)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:439)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have an old version of Guava in the classpath, and that the `com.google.visualization` library needs a more recent one, containing the `ImmutableList.copyOf(Collection)` method.

Add the correct version of Guava in your webapp's libraries.

Comment: Yes, I figured that out and have added the guava jars and it works fine in my local environment. But when deployed to the appengine it appears to be using the older collection jar. How can I fix this on the appengine deployment ?

Comment: I checked ...war/WEB-INF/lib directory for ImmutableList.class and found that the following jars have it: Binary file appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.8.3.jar matches
Binary file appengine-api-labs.jar matches
Binary file apps-marketplace.jar matches
Binary file guava-14.0.1.jar matches
                                                                                             Not sure which jars can be removed to resolve this issue.